# SaveFileDialog error when cancelling the save dialog box

Tags: .net, vb.net, savefiledialog, argumentexception

I have a button to save text files, however if the user chooses cancel in the save dialog box I get this error message:

> an unhandled exception of type 'system.argumentexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: empty path name is not legal.

```
Private sub cmdSave_Click (sender As object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    If rtfTextEditor.Text.Length > 0 then
      SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
      System.IO.File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.Filename, rtfTextEditor.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `ShowDialog()` is a method returning a result.  You are not testing if the user canceled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `SaveFileDialog1.Filename` is `Nothing` when the dialog is cancelled.

You should check the result of the dialog:

```
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.Filename, rtfTextEditor.Text)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not waiting for the result if the `ShowDialog` command before trying to save the file.

The contents of `SaveFileDialog1.Filename` will be null which is probably the source of the error. You need to check if the user hit "Save":

```
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true then
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.Filename, rtfTextEditor.Text)
End If
```